# How to receive XMLHttpRequest with PHP?

Tags: php, xml, ajax, xmlhttprequest, prototypejs

I would like to be able to read XMLHttpRequest that is sent to a PHP page. I am using prototype's Ajax.Request function, and I am sending a simple XML structure.

When trying to print the POST array on the PHP page, I don't get any output.

Any help appreciated.

EDIT: Below is my code

```
<html>
<head>

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var xml='<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8?>';
xml=xml+'<notification>';
xml=xml+'heya there';
xml=xml+'</notification>';
xml=xml+'</xml>';


var myAjax = new Ajax.Request('http://localhost:8080/post2.php',{
    contentType: 'text/xml',
    parameters: xml,
    method: 'post',
    onSuccess: function(transport){ alert(transport.status); alert(transport.responseText); }
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

post2.php

```
Welcome <?php print_r($_POST); ?>!<br />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, please see the edit above for the code.

Comment: So you are getting 

Welcome Array()!

as your result?

Comment: Yes Joseph, thats exactly what I'm getting. I was hoping to get the xml back. This needs to be an text/xml content type due to the server that I am forced to use.

Answer (score 4):

You will read it exactly the sme way you read normal request vars.

`$_GET['varname']` and `$_POST['varname']`

Comment: Unless I'm doing something wrong, I get nothing but an empty array when I print_r $_POST. In my ajax call, my parameter should only be the xml string in the format '<xml>...</xml>, right? Thank you for your input.

Comment: You might try to `print_r($_GET)`, just to see if somehow it's getting send via GET.

Comment: like @Adrian i got an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

php://input allows you to read raw POST data like

```
Welcome <?php print(file_get_contents('php://input')); ?>!<br />
```

Note: php://input is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data".

Comment: $rawData=file_get_contents('php://input');  
// pERFECT upvoted :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) with the `input://` wrapper or [`$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php).

Comment: What the Col is referring to is here: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data

Comment: Straight from the documentation, _"Warning
This feature was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.6.0, and REMOVED as of PHP 7.0.0."_

Answer (score 1):

When you use "method: post" and you want to send a post body, you need the parameter postBody. So something like this might work:

```
var myAjax = new Ajax.Request('http://localhost:8080/post2.php',{
    contentType: 'text/xml',
    postBody: xml,
    method: 'post',
    onSuccess: function(transport){
        alert(transport.status); alert(transport.responseText);
    }
});
```

But why did you build a XML doc around your content? You can simply sent the message "heya there" with the postBody without the XML arround.

Edit: Here you'll find all the Ajax.Request options: http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/options